# Ubuntu 14.04 dual boot with Windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

I use a ASUS N550JV laptop with preloaded Windows 8. I have turned off fast boot and secure boot, and enabled CSM boot. Before installation, I used Windows Disk Management to shrink 15GB out of a harddrive (it's an 128GB SSD. I still have  Windows so I don't have too much space for Ubuntu. But I think 15GB is enough right?) During installation, the an error appeared, saying "Unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda. Executing 'grub-install/dev/sda' failed. This is a fatal error.) Then it asked me to choose a location for boot loader. Could anyone tell me how shall I deal with this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: select the partition where you installed Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I do not speak much English

[Windows 8.1]
Open start menu >> Go to "PC settings" >> "Update & Recovery" >> "Avanced Startup".
[Windows 8]
Open start menu >> Go to "PC settings" >> "General" >> "Avanced Startup".

1. When you restart pc a window is displayed with options, choose "Throubleshoot" >> "Avanced Options" >> "UEFI Fifmware Settings" >> and click en the button "Restart".
2. You will be redirected to the **BIOS configuration**, you need find the Boot configuration, disable "**FastBoot**" and leave **UEFI enabled**, save your configuration and restart the PC.
3. Windows 8 will start again, follow the second step again.
4. When you restart pc a window is displayed with options, choose "Use a device" >> Select your Ubuntu installation, CD-Room or USD device.
5. Before install ubuntu, in the ubuntu partition configuration, be sure create a partition for the boot.
6. Install ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand what "create a partition for the boot" means. Does it mean after shrinking drive in Windows, I should do something besides leaving it "unallocated"? Could you explain a little bit? Thanks!

Comment: Create a new partition of 512mb size, with ext2 partition type, with mount point "/boot" for grub files.